# Zedgraph and labels on bar and pie diagram

Tags: c#, charts, diagram, zedgraph, label

Hi have somewhat success full made tow diagrams, a pie diagram and a horizontal bar diagram but I have tow problems with labels on both.

On my pie diagram, on some combination the labels overlapping

[Example of overlapping in pie diagram http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg831/scaled.php?server=831&filename=zedhelp.png&res=medium](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg831/scaled.php?server=831&filename=zedhelp.png&res=medium)

How can I ensure the labels not overlapping.

---

I also have labels problem with my horizontal bar diagram, I using

```
 BarItem.CreateBarLabels( myPane,false, "");
```

and get the following result

[Bar digram http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg221/scaled.php?server=221&filename=zedgraphbars.png&res=medium](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg221/scaled.php?server=221&filename=zedgraphbars.png&res=medium)

How can I remove the zero, and only get the last values for the bars?

---

I tried search the net, and tried the suggestion here on smilarity topic, and tried many thing,

```
BarItem.CreateBarLabels( myPane,false, "0f");

BarItem.CreateBarLabels( myPane,false, "0f0");
```

tried changing the string format, nothing seem to help.

Trid changin the angle of the labels

```
myPie=myPane.AddPieSlice(yz[tel], Color.Orange, Color.DarkOrange, 45f, 0, navn + " - " + yz[tel].ToString() );

myPie=myPane.AddPieSlice(yz[tel], Color.Orange, Color.DarkOrange, 90f, 0, navn + " - " + yz[tel].ToString() );

myPie=myPane.AddPieSlice(yz[tel], Color.Orange, Color.DarkOrange, 45f, 22, navn + " - " + yz[tel].ToString() );
```

---

But nothing seems to help, some have some idea to

- Ensure no labels overlapping in my pie-diagram
- Only show max value for my horizontal bar diagram.

Thank you.